# Binser Required on MediaWiki. How?

Tags: module, lua, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am using WikiMedia to attempt and host a custom wiki for a sporting league. I am using modules that I have borrowed from a couple of Wikis with similar topics. But I am stuck on an issue I'd really appreciate help with.

I get an error requiring the module 'binser' and everywhere i look I cannot find a place to find that module. I know of Binser, and LuaRocks, but I have no idea how to get those onto my wiki site. I have checked and confirmed I am running the up-to-date systems and I have scribunto fully installed.

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: Which wiki did you get the modules from? Which modules were they? What error *exactly* did you get?

Comment: Leaguepedia - 
my wiki - http://collegiateesports.wiki/index.php/Test1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Fandom did something strange to make that work that they didn't document anywhere. The easiest approach to getting it to work on your own wiki is probably to put a copy of binser.lua [at Module:Binser there](http://collegiateesports.wiki/index.php/Module:Binser), and then replace `require('binser')` with `require('Module:Binser')` [in Module:VarsUtil](http://collegiateesports.wiki/index.php/Module:VarsUtil) and in any other modules you may have that use it.

Comment: Hey, I'm just a random person that happens to work with Scribunto but I am curious - what is the purpose of the Binser module, where did it come from, and where on Fandom do you see something strange in relation to it?

Comment: @Noam It lets you go from almost-arbitrary Lua data to a binary string and back again. It came from https://github.com/bakpakin/binser . The "something strange" is that I *don't* see how Fandom added it, or any documentation for it, but somehow it's there and other modules there can load it.

Comment: Can you give a link to an example of a module on Fandom loading "binser"? I tried `require("binser")`, `require("Module:Binser")`, `require("Dev:Binser")` - all threw errors.

Comment: @Noam https://help.fandom.com/wiki/Extension:Scribunto says "If your wiki has the "binser" library enabled, ...", so apparently not every Fandom wiki will let you use it. Anyway, https://lol.fandom.com/wiki/Module:VarsUtil loads it.

Comment: Ah I see, it might even be a Gamepedia-only thing (Gamepedia has been merged into Fandom last year or so). Anyway, the Lua libraries are server-side and Fandom repository is currently in private mode - I guess they just included it there. If I use an errorous command such as `require('binser').register()` with no parameters, it points out an error on **binser.lua**. Thank you for the information.